# First bit of NRZI

Tags: telecommunications, code, encoding

I was searching for Non-Return-to-Zero Inverted, but no references I couldn't find any reference about the first bit in NRZI.

I know that, in NRZI, `1` refers to `toggle` and `0` refers to `constant`, but I didn't found information about the first bit.

I found examples where the first bit is not specified (unless it's not the first bit ?)

[image: NRZI example]

Other examples give a positive voltage (HIGH) when the first bit is `0`.

[image: NRZI Example with HIGH voltage at the beginning]

While other examples give a negative voltage (LOW) when the first bit is also `0`.

[image: NRZI Example with LOW voltage at the beginning]

Therefore, is there a rule for determining the voltage of the first bit for a NRZI encoding ?

Answer (score 4):

NRZI codes are polarity insensitive. So in general, no, there is no rule, because all that matters is a change. Many interfaces with differential signals can tolerate a signal that is inverted by accident, perhaps by incorrect wiring.

There is even no general rule whether a change means logical 1 bit or logical 0 bit, those are the two variants of NRZI, called NRZM and NRZS.

In some cases the start voltage would never be seen, for example in a situation where the transmitter has already been transmitting while receiver has been turned off or connected later.

There could exist an interface that defines the polarity somehow, for example there could be a kind of parity bit that could be set in a way to force a certain level or transition after the parity bit.